# Three.js Error: "Feedback loop formed between Framebuffer and active Texture" - Rendering Reflections

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I'm using a [CubeCamera](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/CubeCamera) with [WebGLCubeRenderTarget](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLCubeRenderTarget) to render out the surrounding reflection similar to the example here - https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic

But the example keeps giving this error:
[.WebGL-000052760009C700] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Feedback loop formed between Framebuffer and active Texture.
Anyone see the issue?
My Code:

```
const reflection=()=> {

        renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding; // for post processing pass

        cubeRenderTarget1 = new THREE.WebGLCubeRenderTarget( 256, {
            format: THREE.RGBFormat,
            generateMipmaps: true,
            minFilter: THREE.LinearMipmapLinearFilter,
            encoding: THREE.sRGBEncoding // prevents the material's shader from recompiling every frame
        } );

        cubeCamera1 = new THREE.CubeCamera( .01, 10, cubeRenderTarget1 );
        cubeCamera1.position.z = 3
        cubeCamera1.position.y = -4

        reflectionMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
            envMap: cubeRenderTarget1.texture,
            color: 0x011111,
        } );

    }
    reflection()


gltfLoader.load(
          '/exportPackages/sceneMaya.glb', 
          (gltf) =>
          {   

            let meshGLB= gltf.scene.children.find(child => child.name === 'mesh_0')

            meshGLB.material = reflectionMaterial 
            
            scene.add(gltf.scene)           
          })



const animate =()=> {
     cubeCamera1.update( renderer, scene ); }; animate()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fix:
I needed to add

```
meshGLB.visible = false;
cubeCamera1.update( renderer, scene );
meshGLB.visible = true;
```

in my `animate()` to keep the material from rendering itself.